# Asynchronous equivalent to NSString's -initWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsdata

`NSString`'s `initWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` method will automatically detect the correct string encoding to decode the data from the specified URL. However, this method is synchronous, and I am trying to perform the same task asynchronously using an `NSURLConnection`.

The problem I'm having is that when I get the `NSData` from the URL, there's no method to easily convert that data into an `NSString` without knowing the encoding. As I'm pulling in HTML documents the URLs could be any website on the internet, and the encodings will be all sorts of things.

Is there a way of discovering the encoding, to basically perform exactly what `initWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` does?

Comment: Can't you store the NSData that you load asynchronously to disk and open it with a file:// URL? Not tried though...

Answer (score 2):

Here is how your `connection:didReceiveResponse:` delegate method would look like:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSStringEncoding nsEncoding = 0;
    NSString *textEncodingName = [response textEncodingName];
    if (textEncodingName)
    {
        CFStringEncoding cfEncoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((CFStringRef)textEncodingName);
        if (cfEncoding != kCFStringEncodingInvalidId)
        {
            nsEncoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(cfEncoding);
        }
    }

    if (nsEncoding != 0)
    {
        // Great, you have your encoding
    }
    else
    {
        // You are on your own, you have to apply a heuristic
    }
}
```

Also, I suggest you to read [Friday Q&A 2010-02-19: Character Encodings](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-02-19-character-encodings.html) by Mike Ash.

Answer (score 0):

If you are programming for the desktop, you can link in Core Services and use the sniffer provided by the Text Encoding Conversion Manager; see `TECCreateSniffer()` and accompanying functions.

If you are targeting iOS, you will either have to load the data asynchronously, write it to a file asynchronously, and then synchronously use the `NSString` method you mentioned, or attempt to sniff the encoding yourself using any heuristic you can craft or pillage.